# MX Records Not Getting Resolved By Google Apps

Tags: mx-record

My domain is nexussolutions.com.np. My mail is on Google Apps.

My domain host has pointed the MX Records to Google servers. I am getting some mails but not getting many mails.

On mxtoolbox.com, the name servers are timing out
Google Apps is not finding any MX Records

But on http://digwebinterface.com/ only Google is not finding the name servers. Rest all are. Could this be why I get some mails but not all mails? Eg. I get from yahoo.com but not from gmail.com.

Google Apps team says it is an issue with my domain host. But my domain host says they have set up everything correctly and further point to https://www.whatsmydns.net/#MX/nexussolutions.com.np to prove their point.

Appreciate if anyone could shed any light on this.

Comment: It can take up to 24H top propagate a DNS entry worldwide

Answer (score 1):

Right now, `avenueshost.com`, the domain holding the nameservers for your domain, is having problems. Two nameservers are listed for at the `com` level, and when asked for NS records for `avenueshost.com` one says `REFUSED` and the other gives a referral to root (which means it has no information on `avenueshost.com`).

Since that domain doesn't work, the addresses to the nameservers for your domain cannot be found, and so your domain does not work either. This problem may be intermittent, which would explain why you get some mails but not others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with Google's public DNS servers (see the forum thread at end). Your domain resolves fine using other DNS servers except Google's public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) so any client uses Google's public DNS server as resolver will fail to get your MX records (or any records).

Using my cached DNS:

```
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short nexussolutions.com.np mx
10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Using openDNS:

```
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short nexussolutions.com.np mx @208.67.222.222
10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Using google DNS:

```
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short nexussolutions.com.np mx @8.8.8.8
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short nexussolutions.com.np mx @8.8.4.4
```

Using google DNS on my domain for example:

```
arul@cheetah:~$ dig +short selvans.net mx @8.8.4.4
10 selvans.net.
30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
20 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Check the Google Public DNS discussion forum thread below where lot of people had similar issues and request for help.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/public-dns-discuss/7Dd4pzBfpZA